# Why does free crash here?

Tags: c++

The following crashes when it gets to free: (there is reasoning for using void*).

```
bool s = true;

void* arg = &s;
argument = malloc(sizeof(arg));
memcpy(argument,arg,sizeof(arg));
free(argument);
```

argument here is a void*

why does free crash the application?

Thanks

Comment: @Tom: It's tagged C++...

Comment: Are you sure you want `sizeof(arg)`? That will give you the size of a `void*`, not the size of whatever `arg` points to.

Comment: I'd add a null check right there before the memcpy

Comment: Are you sure it's free that's crashing not the memcpy()

Comment: @Reed Yes, I know, but it doesn't look like C++ code. Better said, it looks a lot like C code.

Comment: What if I do not know the size of the object?

Comment: @Milo: "What if I do not know the size of the object?" - if that's the case, how can expect to copy it?

Comment: @Milo: The code will not crash at `free`. If it crashes, it crashes at `memcpy`. If you observe a different behavior, then you must be running a different code, not what you posted here.

Comment: @Milo: If you still think it crashes at the free, then remove the free and see if it crashes! If it still crashes, see my answer (and others) about your memcpy issue.

Comment: -1 for not showing the declaration of `argument`.

Comment: @Milo: If you don't know how many bytes underneath a `void*` are valid, there's essentially nothing you can do with it.  That's why we prefer complete types.  Though some interfaces use a `void*` and a `size_t` (number) together to refer to a generic range of memory.

Comment: @Michael Goldshteyn removing the free prevents the crash

Comment: Always post the *problem*, not the *step*. This is a clear-cut case of posting the step. (We have no idea what this code is for, can only guess, the code is incomplete to us, etc.) Post the problem you're trying to solve, your attempt (this code), and we'll show you what to do. Looks like you want `boost::any`.

Comment: And it probably crashes at `free` because it's the one checking if the memory it's been given is okay, and it probably isn't. But the problem certainly isn't freeing it, since you never modified `argument`.

Comment: @Andrey and @Michael: The code likely is in fact crashing at `free`, even though that's not the "bad code". "Crash later" is a possible behavior on buffer overruns, even though it's a read, not a write.

Comment: @Milo, looks like we solved your problem, then...

Comment: @aschepler: While absolutely anything can happen as a result of undefined behavior, seeing it crash that way in practice would be highly exotic. Which is why I find it very unlikely that it could crash at `free`.

Comment: @AndreyT, @Milo has already stated that removing the free eliminates the crash. So it is becoming doubtful that the free is actually crashing it.

Comment: @AndreyT: crash during `free` or `delete` actually is the single most common symptom of heap corruption.

Comment: @Michael: How in the world do you interpret "no free => no crash" as "the crash isn't happening in free"?

Comment: We cannot move on until you give us more context. (What you're actually executing, trimmed down. What problem you're solving, etc.)

Comment: @Ben Voigt: The point is that there's nothing in the above code to cause heap corruption. Reading outside the bounds is bad, but normally in practice *reading* does not cause any corruption. If it is really crashing at `free`, it would indeed indicate heap corruption, but the popsted code is not to blame for it.

Comment: @AndreyT: You are totally preaching to the choir.  My answer started with "your problem is elsewhere".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is most likely elsewhere.

Since you have some misconceptions about `sizeof (pointer)` I suspect you have a buffer overflow/underflow elsewhere in your program which is resulting in corruption of heap headers, then `free` crashes when it tries to iterate across the corrupted heap.

Others are correct when they point out that you're reading `sizeof (void*)` from a variable which is only `sizeof (bool)`, but since it's on the stack the memory just beyond `s` is almost certainly valid (it might contain other local variables, function arguments, or the return address, none of which would cause a program crash if they were unintentionally read).

`memcpy` can read unaligned data just fine, so even if you were on an architecture that crashes on unaligned accesses this wouldn't be the issue.

Check for overflow of other dynamically allocated buffers.

EDIT: I also want to respond to Milo's comment on a now-deleted question:

> I need to get the object, which could be of any type, allocated – Milo

C++ doesn't work that way.  `malloc` can only allocate memory for POD types, which have to meet some very strong restrictions.  There is NO standard-compliant way, at all, to clone an instance of completely arbitrary type.

Some ways that work reliably on some types are:

- if the type has a base type with a virtual `Clone` function, call `Clone` polymorphically
- if the type is POD and you know the size, use `new char[]` and `memcpy`

Comment: Agreed. If the program has written past the end of other heap allocated arrays/buffers/objects/whatever then it may very well have corrupted the heap in ways that don't show up until a later call to `free`.

Answer (score 2):

arg points to a bool and you're memcopying 4 bytes from it! That's why it crashes. The bool is only one byte.

Comment: Why am I half right, there's nothing wrong with the free itself.

Comment: "The bool is [likely] only one byte [on your platform]."

Comment: While reading extra bytes beyond the variable is bad, that in itself is not likely to cause a crash unless the variable happens to be located near a non-readable area of memory (which isn't that likely).

Comment: @TheUndeadFish: +1, especially true for local variables on stack that grow downward.

Comment: Although you're correct that the memcpy is copying too many bytes, that's unlikely to be the cause of the crash.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    void* argument;

    bool s = true;

    void* arg = &s;
    argument = malloc(sizeof(arg));
    memcpy(argument,arg,sizeof(arg));
    free(argument);

    return 0;
}
```

This code does not crash in VS 2010. In fact, there is nothing illegal about this code, as far as memory management goes. But yes, it does not function as intended because it copies garbage. Assuming a 32-bit environment, you are allocating 4 bytes and setting "argument" to point to these 4 bytes. Then you are copying 4 bytes from the memory that "arg" points to into the 4 bytes that "argument" points to. Yes, 3 of those 4 bytes that arg points to is garbage, but they are there. The compiler is going to allocate 4 bytes on the stack for bool s, not 1. Stacks need to be allocated in chunks of 4 bytes. So the memory is there, although there is 3 bytes that have garbage in them.

I suspect you have a corrupted heap from elsewhere and the call to free just so happens to crash here because of this.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Mario.  Agreed on the cause of the crash, +1 for going beyond my answer and actually running the code snippet.  And because I want more people who understand pointers like you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain it is `free()` that is crashing? It looks more likely that it is the `memcpy()` call. You are blindly copying X bytes, where X is the size of a pointer, from `arg` to `argument`. But you do not know what the size of the data is that `arg` points at.

Comment: Is there a way to know the size of it without knowing what the object is?

Comment: @Milo: no. (cruft to meet minimum comment length)

Comment: No. You need to know what the object is. If it is a structure, `sizeof(struct x)` will work. If it is a string, use `strlen(arg)`.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your comments, you think `sizeof(arg)` is returning the actual size of whatever `arg` is pointing at. This is wrong. It's returning the size of a `void*` pointer.

Your `memcpy` is copying data from beyond the valid end of the source, but that's extremely unlikely to cause a crash.

If `free` is crashing when you give it a valid pointer, it indicates a trashed heap. Since there's no code in the example you show that would invalidate the pointer or trash the heap, I must conclude the problem lies elsewhere, before you get to this code.

Comment: Wow, it's your third answer to this question.

Comment: Third time's the charm? I think it's correct this time, even though someone else has already made the same points.